# How to use a substring filed as a filter in Taleo Client Connect

Tags: export, taleo-connect-client

I'm using the below filter in Connect Client and get an org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog error.

```
<quer:filtering xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:notEqual>
    <quer:projection alias="TestSubStr">
      <quer:substring>
        <quer:field path="Credentials,SSOID"/>
        <quer:integer>8</quer:integer>
        <quer:integer>6</quer:integer>
      </quer:substring>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:string>wlgore</quer:string>
  </quer:notEqual>
</quer:filtering>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "projection" is not needed in that context. If your projectedClass is "Candidate", the following filter should work:

```
<quer:filtering xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:notEqual>
      <quer:substring>
        <quer:field path="Credentials,SSOID"/>
        <quer:integer>8</quer:integer>
        <quer:integer>6</quer:integer>
      </quer:substring>
    <quer:string>wlgore</quer:string>
  </quer:notEqual>
</quer:filtering>
```

If your projectClass is "Application", you need to adjust the path of the SSOID field:

```
<quer:field path="Candidate,Credentials,SSOID"/>
```